# Kafka streams shutting down and don't run

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Good morning guys,

I'm trying to run a Kafka Stream Application but every time that i try, it start and close in sequence. Below is the result printed on the console

```
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - The configuration 'admin.retries' was supplied but isn't a known config.
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] Starting
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [application-brute-test-client] Started Streams client
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from CREATED to RUNNING
[Thread-0] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [application-brute-test-client] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
[kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
[kafka-admin-client-thread | application-brute-test-client-admin] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager - [AdminClient clientId=application-brute-test-client-admin] Metadata update failed
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.
[kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [application-brute-test-client] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to NOT_RUNNING
[Thread-0] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [application-brute-test-client] Streams client stopped completely
```

watch out for the following line:

```
[application-brute-test-client-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
```

The application was informed to shut down, but i don't know why. Can someone help me with this problem?

Here is my simple code only to test the stream:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "myserver");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "application-brute-test");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "application-brute-test-client");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE); // Enable exacly once feature
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass()); // Set a default key serde
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass()); // Set a default key serde

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> input = builder.stream("neurotech_propostas", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
input.print(Printed.toSysOut());
KStream<String, String> output = input.mapValues((value) -> value.toUpperCase());

output.to("brute-test-out");

KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
stream.cleanUp();
stream.start();

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(stream::close));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem I simply stopped using JUnit to run the Stream and executed through a Main class. Running Kafka Streams via JUnit was causing this trouble.

Maybe in this envirorment the JUnit don't hold the Thread execution?

Comment: For testing your topologies you can use kafka-streams-test-utils. More details can be found here: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html